# how to connect the database to my SEARCH button for android

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I just click the SEARCH button, retrieve the data from my SQLite database, and display it in my app?

My Activity:

```
public class EKaDEMActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    //EditText ET;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "Dic_id";
    public static final String colID="_id";
    public static final String colKD="KD_word";
    public static final String colENG="ENG_word";
    public static final String colMAL="Malay_word";
    public static final String colAudio="KD_audio";

    private static final String dbName="Dictionary";
    private static final String dbTable="tbl_Dictionary";
    private static final int dbVersion = 2;

    static final String viewEmps="ViewEmps";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_one);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  


        EditText ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AutoTextBox);
        ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AutoTextBox);

        String s = ET.getText().toString();
        TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DefTextView);
        TV.setText("Welcome Using Kadazandusun-English-Malay Mobile Dictionary Application");
        boolean r = s.contentEquals("dog");
        if (r == true)
        {
            String str = "  M: Anging \n\n" + "  KD: Tasu ";
            TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DefTextView);
            text.setText(str);
        }
        else
        {
            TV.setText("   Word not found");

        }               
    }


}
```

This is my Database.java

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "Dic_id";
public static final String colID="_id";
public static final String colKD="KD_word";
public static final String colENG="ENG_word";
public static final String colMAL="Malay_word";
public static final String colAudio="KD_audio";

private static final String dbName="Dictionary";
private static final String dbTable="tbl_Dictionary";
private static final int dbVersion = 1;

static final String viewEmps="ViewEmps";

public Database(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + dbTable + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            colKD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            colENG + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            colMAL + " TEXT NOT NULL, );");

    db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW "+viewEmps+
            " AS SELECT "+dbTable+"."+colID+" AS _id,"+
            " "+dbTable+"."+colKD+","+
            " "+dbTable+"."+colENG+","+
            " "+dbTable+"."+colMAL+""+
            " FROM "+dbTable
            );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ dbTable);
    onCreate(db);
}

 void AddWord(Word wrd)
 {


     SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();


    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    cv.put(colKD, wrd.getKD());
    cv.put(colENG, wrd.getENG());
    cv.put(colMAL, wrd.getMAL());
    //cv.put(colDept,2);

    db.insert(dbTable, colKD, cv);
    db.close();


}

 public int UpdateWrd(Word wrd)
 {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(colKD, wrd.getKD());
    cv.put(colENG, wrd.getENG());
    cv.put(colMAL, wrd.getMAL());
    return db.update(dbTable, cv, colID+"=?", new String []{String.valueOf(wrd.getID())});

 }

 public void DeleteWrd(Word wrd)
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
     db.delete(dbTable,colID+"=?", new String [] {String.valueOf(wrd.getID())});
     db.close();

 }

Cursor getWord()
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

     Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+viewEmps,null);
     return cur;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should read some more tutorials on SQLite and Android, you understand some of it but you could learn a little more.

You need to create a Database object in EKaDEMActivity, maybe like this:

```
Database database;
...

onCreate() {
    ...
    database = new Database(this);
}
```

Replace this:

```
boolean r = s.contentEquals("dog");
if (r == true)
```

with something like:

```
Cursor cursor = database.getWord(s);
if(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ...
    text.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(colKD)));
```

And in getWords():

```
Cursor getWord(String word) {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

     return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+viewEmps + " WHERE " + colENG + "=?", new String[] { word });
}
```

This only searches for an English word and displays the matching word from your KD column, you will have to change it as needed.  Understand that getting a new writable database every time you search for a word is very inefficient, you should only call getWritableDatabase() once and save db in a class variable.  Also you should close your cursors when you are done or pass them to the Activity so it will automatically close them for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Add these two functions to your data base class.**

```
public Cursor searchall()throws Exception// For searching all record 
{
    return db.rawQuery("Select * from info ORDER BY regno ",null);
}

public Cursor search(String regno)throws Exception // for searching record with where clause
{
    return db.rawQuery("Select * from info where regno='"+regno+"'",null);
}
```

**Add this code to your Search button**

```
btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) 
{
    try 
    {
    String num = regno.getText().toString();
        dba.open();
        cursor = dba.search(num);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            do 
            {
                regno.setText(cursor.getString(0));
                name.setText(cursor.getString(1));
                fname.setText(cursor.getString(2));
                age.setText(cursor.getString(3));
                city.setText(cursor.getString(4));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
            dba.close();
        }
    }
}
```